# OpenCV: Background subtracting issue when one `VideoCapture` instance is used

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Please have a look at the below code

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cv::VideoCapture cam1,cam2;
    cam1.open(0);
    //cam2.open(0);

    Mat im,im2;

    cam1>>im;
    cam1>>im2;

    while(true)
    {
        cam1>>im;

        for(int i=0;i<15000;i++)
        {


        }
        cam1>>im2;

        Mat im3 = im2-im;

        imshow("video",im3);

        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    waitKey(0); 
}
```

I am trying to identify the difference (in other terms, motion) by subtracting the images. However what I get is a 100% blank screen. If I use 2 `VideoCapture` instances capture frames and load them to `im` and `im2`, then it works. But I must not use 2 `VideoCapture` instances, I must only use 1. what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compare `im.data` and `im2.data` you will find that they are pointing to the same buffer.

Change your code to this

```
Mat im,im2;

cam1>>im;
im = im.clone();
cam1>>im2;
```

When you read a frame from VideoCapture, it does not copy the data.
If you want to copy the data before it gets overwritten by the next frame you have to do it yourself.

If you have two different VideoCapture instances, you already have separate buffers so the  problem does not occur.